# Is it Possible to Remove the Autofocus Points From the Viewfinder When Using a Split Focusing Screen?

Tags: autofocus, viewfinder, focus-point-selection, focusing-screen

I'm new to photography and recently purchased a Canon 60D.  I purchased a [split focusing screen from amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005ODKAZ8) and replaced the stock focusing screen.

I still see the autofocus points in the viewfinder, but I would rather do without them.  I can remove the two screws in the picture and then remove the second piece of glass with the autofocus points on it (not the focusing screen), but then none of my pictures seem to focus accurately.

Is there any way to forgo the autofocus points in my viewfinder?  Perhaps replace the second piece of glass with a blank one?

[image: Canon 60D body]

Comment: To clarify: Are you planning to never use the camera's autofocus system?

Comment: I plan on going long periods of time without using it, so if removing the overlay points means no autofocus, then that's fine.

Comment: @Calab What does the focusing screen and the other piece of glass with the AF points inscribed on them have to do with the actual AF system? The light path from the lens to the PDAF sensor does not pass through the focusing screen.

Comment: Some camera use LCD focus point indicator and could be turned off. Are you sure this is not the case for 60D?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to forgo the autofocus points in my viewfinder? Perhaps replace the second piece of glass with a blank one?

You would need to replace the piece in question with another piece that is both the same thickness and has the same refractive index. You need the former so that the surface of the focusing screen remains equidistant from the lens as before (assuming it was properly adjusted before so that the light path from the lens to the focusing screen via the reflex mirror is the same distance as the light path from the lens to the imaging sensor when the mirror is moved up and out of the way). Differences in the latter *might* be correctable using the viewfinder's diopter adjustment wheel.

Note that the lights associated with the AF points would still be projected onto the focusing screen. The only thing you would eliminated are the outlines of the AF points that are visible even when the camera is turned off. The lights will always light up to show the selected AF point during AF point selection. They can be enabled or disabled to light up when AF is achieved via the Custom Function menu at *C.Fn. III-3 Superimposed display*.